# How to create dynamic leaflet plot by using selectinput variable selection on reactive data in r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am running a **leaflet** plot in `shiny` that is already partially dynamic with selection to create **reactive data** but having **troubles** in dynamic variable selection on **reactive data** in **renderLeaflet({})** section.

looking to dynamically change: `district_map_data()$Daily_confirmed` with `district_map_data()$input$id_districts_var_selection`.

**Working code below** when variable is fixed to (`Daily_confirmed`):

```
 district_map_data <- reactive({
        
        req(input$id_state_for_district)
        
        district_map_data <- state_level_map %>% 
            data preprocessing code ...
    }) %>% 
        bindCache(input$id_state_for_district)
 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------ #   
    
    output$id_state_map <- renderLeaflet({
        req(input$id_districts_var_selection)
        
        pal_district <- colorBin(palette = "plasma", bins = 4, 

                                 # Need dynamic code here
                                 domain = district_map_data()$Daily_confirmed) # {input$id_districts_var_selection}
        
        label_district = paste("Latest Daily Cases:",

                               # Need dynamic code here
                               as.character(district_map_data()$Daily_confirmed)) %>%
                               lapply(htmltools::HTML)
        
        district_map_data() %>% leaflet() %>%

            addPolygons(
                label = label_district,

                # Need dynamic code here
                fillColor = ~ pal_district(Daily_confirmed)) %>%
            
            addLegend(position = "bottomleft",
                      pal = pal_district,

                      # Need dynamic code here
                      values = ~ district_map_data()$Daily_confirmed,
                      opacity = 0.7)
        
    })
```

One possible way I know is to **pivot longer** the variables into 1 & filter it within the **reactive data** itself with the **selectInput** selection but will only try that if I do not find any solution here.

Any help is much appreciated !!!

Comment: I think you're a victim of *non-standard evaluation* (NSE).  Leaflet appears to have its own flavour of NSE, which differs from the one used by tidyverse.  [This](https://community.rstudio.com/t/functional-programming-around-leaflet-with-nse/26477) may help, but is not hugely optimistic.

Comment: Thanks @Limey for sharing this. I am already not a fan of `metaprogramming` in `r` as it gave me nightmare many times. I guess I will just `pivot longer` the data in the `reactive data` itself & `filter` it in there and then have just single var name everywhere in the leaflet code. Thanks again !!